# jquery drag and drop contacts into a form field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to work out how is it possible to use jquery to drag a item from a block of contacts (as an example mobile numbers) and drop them into a form field or a text area, then removing them by having a close button (some thing like the iphone messaging when adding contacts).

You help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean a close button inside the text area

Comment: I can only give an idea because I implemented it in one of my projects. You can make a div in which you may drag and drop items and after dropping append a tag like button with that text and a cross(of course). And as far as input box is concerned, keep it hidden and update its value after every editing done in that div. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(function() {
      $( "ul > li" ).draggable({
          appendTo: "body",
          helper: "clone"
      });
      $("div").droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
              createNode(ui.draggable.text(), $(ui.draggable))
              $(ui.draggable).hide();

          }
      });
  });

  function createNode(text, origNode) {
     $("div").append(
         $('<span class="node"/>').html(text).append(
             $('<span class="close"/>').click(function () {
                 origNode.show();
                 $(this).parent().remove();
             }).html('x')
         )
     );
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/G6fmF/

Comment: Thanks mate but the items are not draggable!

Comment: I did not get 'not draggable'. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to do something like http://goo.gl/FD3tP ?

Comment: I meant in your example I am not able to drag the texts! and yes, something like the link you put. that is ability of dragging contacts and then being able to remove them by clicking a x near each entry. hope you can help me out. thanks.

Comment: oh I just realized I can drag the texts only when I select them (double click). before select they are not selectable. am I right?

Comment: Oh, actually jquery.com restricted accessing the js files from their server so js error was there. You can see the updated demo above.

Comment: mate on your previous example I was able to type on the second box, but now its not a text area! I was thinking in a way you can add by typing and also remove by backspace!

Comment: In that case, the logic would be to add a textbox below the dropable div tag and attach some events to capture enter/backspace. I've updated the the demo, you can visit the same url above. - would like an upvote ;-)

Comment: would love to give you but apparently I need reputation or something. thanks for the help dude. I also had a look at ur weblog, its pretty useful :)

Comment: @user1427257: I've upvoted your questions so that you can up vote any stacker. Glad my solution worked for me.